# Using MigLayout imported from .jar

Tags: java, import, jar, miglayout

I'm usually working in Eclipse. In my program, I'm using this miglayout-4.0-swing.jar file from this source: [link](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/versions/4.0/). 
Somehere in the .jar file is class with [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). 
I use these imports:

```
import net.miginfocom.layout.Grid; 
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
```

//It's from the jar file.

In Eclipse i just add library: 
Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs/Add external JARs -> path to  miglayout-4.0-swing.jar 
So in Everything working. 
But I need to run it from terminal: java  (I don't use packages so i use just classes from bin) but there is the problem with the .jar file, cause myMain class probably don't know where are the classes for that .jar (doesn't work the imports upper).
I tryed copy the .jar file to same directory where are the classes. Doesn't help.
What should I do to add the .jar file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line `java` command don't know where to look for the miglayout jar file. You should run in from command line like

> java -cp path_to_miglayout_jar myMain

Comment: Could you be more specific..? Post the error with stack trace, otherwise I cannot help you..

Comment: There were some other problems - somehow the versions of jdk and jre weren same. So I fixed this. And this command should look like: `java -cp "path_to_miglayout_jar/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar:." myMain`
problem was missing the `.` after `:`, the `.` was necesary cause it is classpath to myMain.class
I found that in linux I use `:` in windows `;` as separator.

Comment: And what about edit it? Cause what you'we suggested little helped me, but it didn't worked cause it's in general wrong and I would not misslead someone who could have similar problem. I get the solution from one expert on java from our university. Your solution's missing path to the java sources, which could differ from the jar path. I would edit it and then accept it if I have enough privileges to do it. The solution what is in my comment is the right solution and work for all cases in linux with path separator `:` and in windows with path separator `;` Correct your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm little confused. From your answer follows, that you're trying to run already compiled *.class file with miglayout as library (*.jar). So what's 'Your solution's missing path to the java sources' you're writing about..? Anyway, you may answer your question by yourself and accept it, that's also the way.

Comment: @Sorceror: to run a class you still need . on the classpath for java to find the class.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but for the sake of completeness:

You need both `.` (current directory) and `miglayout-4.0.jar` to be on your classpath. You have two ways to do so. The easiest is to use -cp

In your case, you'll need to run:

```
java -cp "path_to_miglayout_jar/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar:." myMain
```

or if you work on a Windows OS:

```
java -cp "path_to_miglayout_jar/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar;." myMain
```

If unsure if you need to use a `;` (colon) or a `:` (or whatever the OS is asking for), you can take a look at `java.io.File.pathSeparator` which contains the correct separator.

The other way would be to change your CLASSPATH variable.