# Importing miglayout.

Tags: java, linux, swing, miglayout

My problem is very similar to the one described in this post:

[Can't use jar library in my java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322092/cant-use-jar-library-in-my-java-file)

I am trying to use a MigLayout in one of my projects. I am on Linux, so to import it from the command line to my current project I use:

```
javac -classpath $PWD/miglayout-4.0.jar  $PWD/*.java
```

Both .jar and Main class fort the project are in the same(current) directory. 
Then I add an import statement like so:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.*;
```

And...it gives me a compiler error which says that the package does not exist. 
So I decided to try if downloading a swing-only version of it and used this command:

```
javac -cp $PWD/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar:. Windows.java
```

As was suggested here: [Using MigLayout imported from .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252888/using-miglayout-imported-from-jar)

I also looked at other links like: 
[Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)
And more...

Still can't figure it out.

As the last resort I tried to unjar the archive and use it, but it also gives an error.

Comment: why not use IDE and manage the dependency there...

Answer (score 0):

You can "unjar" the Miglayout jar and use the classes in the jar to compile your project. Just replace the jar with the directory (dir) where the Miglayout class files are located.

```
javac -classpath $PWD/miglayout_directory  $PWD/*.java
```